# Get list of lines that begin with a pattern

Tags: regular-expression, register

I have two files written in php, both with a bunch of functions. I need to compare these function names with the other file, so I'm trying to get a list of all lines that begin with `function`. Preferably I would like to have these lines copy to a register. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be done pretty easily with the `global` command. I would try this:

```
:let @a=''
:g/^function/y A
```

First we must call `:let @a=''` to make sure that the 'a' register is empty.

Then, the global command is used to apply a command to every line matching a certain regex. In this case, the regex is `^function`, and the command is `y A` (the *ex* command, not the normal mode command). From `:h :y`

```
                            *:y* *:yank* *E850*
:[range]y[ank] [x]  Yank [range] lines [into register x]. Yanking to the
            "* or "+ registers is possible only when the
            |+clipboard| feature is included.
```

Yanking into uppercase *A* as opposed to lowercase *a* means that the yanked text is *appended* to the register.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use `vimgrep`. It wouldn't put them in a register but you'd get this list pretty easily.

```
:vimgrep /^function/ ./*.php
:cw
```

`:cw` Opens the quick fix so you can see the result of your search.

See [`:help :vimgrep`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3Avimgrep) and [`:help quickfix`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#quickfix) for more info.